# Passing the output of the last command to sed as an argument

Tags: bash, sed, xargs

Basically, I'm wanting to automate adding something to xorg.conf in the right place, I've used some commands to get the line number of the line I want to manipulate, but I'm not really sure how to go about passing this line number (as an argument and NOT something to be manipulated) to sed. I have been told about xargs and looked at the docs on it, but after some reading and experimentation I can't seem to get it to work.

In case anyone can think of a better method entirely, the process I want to automate is just finding the line containing both "Identifier" and "Monitor0" (there will only be one) and adding a line below it. The problem with just finding Monitor0 and manipulating that line is that there are *multiple* lines with Monitor0 in.

I've got this far:

```
fgrep -n "Monitor0" </etc/X11/xorg.conf | fgrep "Identifier" | cut -f1 -d:
```

This gives out the line number which I'm wanting to pass to sed, but I'm not really sure how to do it.

...or is there a simpler way which I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it (thanks #cogs on SynIRC), solution for this particular issue is as follows:

```
sed '/\bIdentifier\b.*\bMonitor0\b/ a\\tOption "NoDDC"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a framework to do this in a perl script, but i don't have that have experience with sed so you would have to take core of the details.

Write a perl script which first identifies the line (not the line number) at which you have to append. (Something like: $line = system("fgrep -n ..."); )
Then run sed like this:`sed s/$line/$line.'\n'.$linetoadd/ <$oldfile >$newfile`.

Comment: Sadly I don't know perl well enough to confidently do that, and I'd rather just have it as a command. I'm sure it can be done with xargs, I'm just not experienced enough to work out how.